# MarkLogic : Persist and reuse a Xquery result

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I was wondering if there is a way for me use a result from search function in MarkLogic and use it in multiple transformation queries that I have.

For eg.

```
    let $uris := cts:uris(("/example/"),(),cts:element-query(xs:QName("cd:documentTitle"),cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("cd:id"),"abc")))
return (fn:count($uris), $uris)[1 to 20]
```

The above query say returns me URI for 20 documents. How can I save this result or re-use this result for multiple transformations that I have. All of them working on the same result set but performing different tasks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't bother. cts:uris is pretty fast. Just consider using a limit option on cts:uris, rather than getting a subsequence in the return part.

Comment: Please explain how this code is used in more detail the full context will help determine what can help. Server fields, registered queries, or like grtjn mentioned (already pulling from a lexicon). Context matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're using CORB to process data based on that return.

You could instead run your query in QConsole or similar and write the following in your URIs module:

```
let $uris = ("/1.xml", "/2.xml", ...)
return (fn:count($uris), $uris)
```